# Unable to put BoxSizer inside Notebook in wxpython

Tags: python, python-3.x, wxpython, wxwidgets

I am trying to put a login/password page inside one tab of a `wx.Notebook`. But `wx.BoxSizer` doesn't work - it piles the labels and buttons.

Here is my code.

```
    # Define the tab content as classes:
 class TabOne(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)

        # USERNAME LABEL
        user_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        user_lbl = wx.StaticText(self, label="Username:")
        user_sizer.Add(user_lbl, 0, wx.ALL | wx.CENTER, 5)

        # USERNAME CONTROL TEXT
        self.user = wx.TextCtrl(self)
        user_sizer.Add(self.user, 0, wx.ALL | wx.CENTER, 5)

        # Password LABEL
        password_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

        pass_lbl = wx.StaticText(self, label="Password:")
        password_sizer.Add(pass_lbl, 0, wx.ALL | wx.CENTER, 5)

        # PASSWORD CONTROL TEXT
        self.password = wx.TextCtrl(self, style=wx.TE_PASSWORD | wx.TE_PROCESS_ENTER)
        password_sizer.Add(self.password, 0, wx.ALL, 5)

        # MAIN SIZER FOR TAB A
        main_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        main_sizer.Add(user_sizer, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        main_sizer.Add(password_sizer, 0, wx.ALL, 5)

        login_btn = wx.Button(self, label="Login")
        login_btn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON,
                       handler=self.onLogin)

        wx.Panel.SetSizer(main_sizer)

    def onLogin(self):
        return self.bot.login(username=self.user, password=self.password, use_cookie=True)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are assigning the `main_sizer` in a wrong way. Change the line `wx.Panel.SetSizer(main_sizer)` to `self.SetSizer(main_sizer)`. Your `TabOne` class comes from a `wx.Panel` so in the same way you are making your widgets children of self, you will assign the main_sizer to self.

Comment: You are correct, I changed it as self.SetSizer(main_sizer), it works. Thank you very much...

Comment: @nuriselcuk Happy to help. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.